# Fetch details from one list to another on comparing user email address.

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am looking for some guidance regarding SharePoint 2010 lists.

Scenario:

Let's say this is List-A having details of user profile.

Let's say it is List-B which has some other data and I have one column having user email address, in this list on form load event when user login it just fetch user email address. In this list I have to introduce one column that wil bring details from user profile list on the basis of email address. If email address doesn't exist in List-A then column will remain blank otherwise it will show user required text in the same column.

I hope that I have given enough details what I required.

Any idea would be great.

Furthermore, I don't have visual studio installed that's why I cannot do programing therefore any other workaround idea would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SPServices Library based on Jquery. You can do this on client side by editing the form in SharePoint Designer.

Look at this function `SPCascadeDropdowns()`

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns